# Copying data from datagridview to multiple textboxes

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Need help with datagridview...

I am using Visual Studio 3.5 for my project and MS access2000 db for the backend.

My requirement is that upon clicking on a textbox, a datagrid should appear and upon doubleclicking on the desired cell, its values get copied in the textboxes and the datagridview disappears. The trouble is that I have to fill multiple textboxes using the same method but should hold different data from the same datagridview. How can I do that??? Please help...!

Comment: Try some thing u r self and upload the code if not got exact solution........Its possible u can achieve it....

Comment: I tried... but i am not getting the method how to do it... like, i can understand that in the textbox1_click event, i have to show the datagridview... but then, how do i copy the data from datagridview into the textboxes, which are variables, for the same datagrid has to feed about 10 different datas in as many sets of textboxes...

Comment: It will help us if you can post the code that you have tried and let us know how it doesn't achieve what you want.

Comment: Please post more information. Otherwise risking to get closed as non-constructive.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/77j3uzbez/

http://postimg.org/image/afnl80xor/


These are links to my form and the codes i have been trying... as you can see, i'm trying to copy the data from the dgv and then paste it to the textboxes, but i don't know how and when to call the event that will paste the data to the textboxes..

Comment: @SaurabhSuman i just saw your question, i can help you with examples if still need it?

Answer (score 0):

DataGridViews have a lot of events you can use. Of the top of my head, I believe one is something alone the lines of

```
Private sub OnCellContentClick(some args, DataGridView.OnCellContentClick e)
  someTextBox.text = DataDrigView.item(e.colIndex,e.rowIndex)
end sub
```

This code ***won't*** compile, It's been a while since I've used VB.net, but its something like that.

Comment: I came across this code during my search. but the problem is that i cannot define a single textbox for the abovementioned code. If u saw the image of my form, u will see that there are 10 sets of 2 textboxes, and each set should be fed the data only when the dgv appears upon clicking on a txtbox of a given set... For example, if i click on txtbox1, the dgv should appear.. and then when i doubleclick the desired data, it should automatically get fed in txtbox1 and txtbox2. again, when i click on textbox3, same events occur again, but data will go to txtbox3 & txtbox4. and so on..

Comment: perhaps if in your TextBoxClicked event you populated a page property that told you which TextBox set had been clicked? Then when your DataGrid is clicked, you'd know which TextBox set to populate.